# Inverse z-transformation

Tags: laplace-transform, z-transform

I have following equation $G(z)={z+0.5\over z^2-1.5z+0.5}$ with Partial fraction decomposition I got $G(z)={3\over z-1}+{-2\over z-0.5}$
usually we look in a conversion table how to do the reverse z-transformation.

unfortunately I cannot find anything suiting my equation. I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could help me!
Thank you very much.

Comment: Where did $x$ go? It can not just disappear after you make a partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: it didn't go anywhere sorry.. there should be a $z$ instead. I fixed it!

Comment: But then $G$ isn't really a function of $x$ anymore, is it?

Comment: Damn I really got my variables mixed up... fixed

Comment: It should be doable with the tables in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform if you combine with substitution and the time reversal and linearity properties which are described on the same wikipedia page.

Comment: okay they didn't have that on the german wikipedia site. they use $z^-1$ is this the same as z in my case?

Comment: yes changing sign of z variable exponent gives time reversal. you can also use {} for grouping exponents together in the mathjax. z^{-1} would give both minus sign and the one raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are actually $z$ transforms (not Laplace transforms), the main thing you want to refer back to is

$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n.$$

Now do some algebra to make each of your expressions look like  $\frac{C}{1-u(z)}$ for some constant $C$ and a suitable expression $u(z)$, and then plug into the formula above. (Hint: in the first one $u(z)$ is just $z$.)

Comment: I came as far as ${-3\over1-z}+{4\over1-2z}$. I can't get rid of the $1-2z$. does this still work? EDIT: it does.. ${1\over1-az}=a^n*\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$

Comment: But I guess the $a^n$ goes inside the sum doesn't it? isn't quite clear in the table from wikipedia. Where do I put the constant $C$ then? Like this: $\frac{C}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C*z^n$?

Comment: Yes, the $a^n$ goes inside the sum, so if you have $\frac{C}{1-az}$ then it has coefficients $Ca^n$ for $n=0,1,\dots$.

Answer (score 0):

**Z Transform of (a^n )u(n) is z / (z-a)**

Using Time Shifting property

Z Transform of a^(n-1)u(n-1) will be 1 / (z-a)

Now i think you have your answer